# Finding the limit set of a particular ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I want to solve exercise 3 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-034-honors-differential-equations-spring-2009/recitations/MIT18_034s09_rec18_rec0514.pdf):

> In the competitive system 
>   $$x'=x(k-ax-by), \quad y'=y(m-cx-dy), \quad k,m,a,b,c,d>0 $$
>   if the lines $ax+by=k$ and $cx+dy=m$ do not intersect in the first quadrangle $x,y>0$ find the limit set.

I'm not sure what is meant by *the limit set*, but I believe it's either the $\alpha$- or $\omega$- limit set as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_set#Definition_for_flows). The critical points of the system are
$$(0,0),(0,m/d),(k/a,0) $$ 
as well as the intersection of the two lines, it it exists. Hence there are no critical points in the domain $D=\{(x,y):x,y>0\}$. Moreover, the axes $x=0$ and $y=0$ are invriant sets of the flow. This means that if the initial data is $(x_0,y_0) \in D$, the solution will remain in $D$ for all time $t$. I've tried solving the system numerically with various parameter values, but couldn't see a pattern. My question is: what is the limit set given the above?

Thank you!